# How to find nearest values between collection in java?

Tags: java, collections

I need to find out the key from Hashmap after finding the nearest values of Arraylist.

I have a Hashmap like below:

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList> map=new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList>;
map.put(1,new ArrayList(0.45,0.55));
map.put(2,new ArrayList(1.45,1.55));
map.put(3,new ArrayList(3.45,3.55));
```

And, I have an Arraylist as :

```
ArrayList checklist=new ArrayList();
checklist.add(1.35);
checklist.add(1.60);
```

Now I need to compare checklist with Hashmap's value (ie, Arraylist).

If I compare above two collections, probably i will get the key '2' from the hashmap.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
Integer index;

Set<Integer> keys = map.keySet();
Iterator it = keys.iterator();

while(it.hasNext())
{
    Integer key = it.next();
    double dist = distance( map.get(key), checklist);
    if( dist < min )
    {
        min = dist;
        index = key;
    }
}
```

Then the variable index has your desired value. The method distance returns your preferred distance metric. It seems like you can use 1-norm:

```
public double distance(ArrayList<Double> a1, ArrayList<Double> a2)
{
    if(a1.size() != a2.size())
        return Double.MAX_VALUE;

    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<a1.size(); i++)
        sum += Math.abs(a1.get(i)-a2.get(i));

    return sum;
}
```

Also, always parametrize your ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Double> checklist=new ArrayList<Double>();
```

and

```
new ArrayList(0.45, 0.55)
```

will give you an error. I assume what you really want to do is create the ArrayList and then add those values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try by your way and then come back.

Comment: I tried with above logic. It will return key 1 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) on `1.35` etc and then use the result to look up the entry in the map.

This only works if the map contains keys for all possible integers can `Math.round()` can return on your data. If it does not (e.g. there are gaps), then `HashMap` is not a suitable data structure. In that case you could use [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [`ceilingEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry(K))/[`floorEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry(K)).

Answer (score 0):

Calculate average value of every List from map and then compare with average from your checklist.

Take map entry which have smallest `Math.abs(avgCheckList-avgMapItem);`

Answer (score 0):

Use proper template parametrization and it will make your life easier.

```
Map<Integer, List<Double>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Double>>();
map.put(1, new ArrayList<Double>() {{add(0.45); add(0.55);}});
map.put(2, new ArrayList<Double>() {{add(1.45); add(1.55);}});
map.put(3, new ArrayList<Double>() {{add(3.45); add(3.55);}});

List<Double> checklist = new ArrayList<Double>();
checklist.add(1.35);
checklist.add(1.60);
```

Then calculate the difference between the values of the checklist and the values of the array lists in the map, find the minimum value, and that's that.